# Error while installing NLTK

Tags: 14.04

I am following the steps given in this link to Install NLTK http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/NLTK/NLTK_install.php.But I am getting error while running following command   `sudo pip install -U numpy` .

output(last part):

```
    out = check_types(*a, **kw)

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 293, in check_types

    "Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\

SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-lYs_os/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Vu1Dyw-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lYs_os/numpy
```

please help to do this? Is there ny alternate way?!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `python-dev` as the error suggests:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

`python-devel` is for RHEL-based systems, and `python-dev` for Debian-based ones.